# rust tokio::spawn await after mutexguard

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I cant place a async function after i lock a mutex. Example 2 works, while example 1 doenst. Why is that. I already disposed of temp, so why is it causing a problem

```rs
let temp = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
tokio::spawn(async move {
        let temp = temp.lock().unwrap();
        drop(temp);
        async_func().await
    });
```

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
        async_func().await;
        let temp = temp.lock().unwrap();
        drop(temp);
    });
```

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely future created by async block is not `Send` Help: within `impl futures_util::Future<Output = ()>`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, i32>` Note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await Note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a block instead of `drop`.

```rs
let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
    {
        let temp = temp.lock().unwrap();
    }
    async_func().await
});
```

This is a bug ([57478](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57478), [87309](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87309)), so the `drop` version will work when [97331](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97331) is merged.

Comment: This is [issue #57478](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57478), and it is fixed by the nightly `-Zdrop-tracking`.